# Interpolation in QGIS shows wrong output result

Tags: qgis, interpolation, kriging, nearest-neighbor, inverse-distance-weighted

[image]I have done interpolation (IDW and Nearest Neighbour) in QGIS. But interestingly the output shows the wrong result. The area where I have a huge number of points results in a lower Z value (it is supposed to have a higher Z value). 
Is it because of the overlapping points?

Another doubt is that kriging algorithm does not show the predicted value (i.e. predicted value is not in the Z value range `-160` to `80`), though the output curve is meaningful. The prediction shows values in the range `-120` to `-70` or so. What might be the reason?

Comment: Could you please specify what kind of data are you using or upload almost a portion of that raster ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited the question and added the screenshot.

Comment: What kind of information does the point layer represent?

Comment: It is about the signal strength

Comment: We need to see some of your dataset and how exactly (tools and parameters) you performed the interpolation. The picture is not helping too much because we can't see the legend and what colors from point represent. If you want to keep the kriging part of the question, add details about it as well. Tks.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I figured out that the error is due to the  default settings which set a positive number instead of a negative value.Basically, the error is due to data file.